# Serverless-fastify-TypeORM: Cannot read property 'getParameters' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeorm, fastify

I am creating a Rest api with fastify, serverless and typeorm, it works locally without the serverless and with nodemon, but it doesn't work when I add serverless

my code:

```
import fastifySwagger from "fastify-swagger";
    import fastify, { FastifyInstance } from "fastify";
    import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";
    
    import fincaRoutes from "./api/routes/fincas";
    
    const server: FastifyInstance<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse> =
        fastify({
            logger: true,
        });
    
    server.register(fastifySwagger, {
        exposeRoute: true,
        routePrefix: "/docs",
        swagger: { info: { title: "fastify-api", version: "1.0" } },
    });
    
    server.register(require("middie"));
    
    server.register(fincaRoutes);
    
    server.get("/", async (request, reply) => {
        reply.send({ text: "Hello, Friend" });
    });
```

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["ES5", "ES6", "DOM"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": [
        "server.ts",
        ".build/**/*.js",
        "api/**/*.ts",
        "api/controllers/items.ts",
        "api/controllers/fincas.ts"
    ]
}
```

and the function that I want to run:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { getConnection, getRepository } from "typeorm";

import { Finca } from "../db/entities/Finca";

export const getFincas = async (_req: any, reply: any) => {
    const finca = new Finca();
    const fincas = await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select("finca")
        .from(Finca, "finca")
        .getMany();

    reply.send(fincas);
};
```

this is the entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity("table_finca")
export class Finca {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column("varchar")
    nombre: string;

    @Column("varchar")
    direccion: string;

    @Column("varchar")
    email: string;

    @Column("varchar")
    nombreContacto: string;

    @Column("double")
    latitud: number;

    @Column("double")
    longitud: number;

    @Column("bigint")
    telefono: number;

    @Column("bigint")
    celular: number;

    @Column("boolean")
    habitada: boolean;

    @Column("bigint")
    informacionEncuesta_id: number;

    @Column("bigint")
    institucion_id: number;

    @Column("bigint")
    municipio_id: number;

    @Column("bigint")
    vereda_id: number;
}
```

I have tried several ways, but with all of them it gives me different errors and I can't find more ways to continue, please help.